# Web application deployment

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am buiding an internet web application using c# ASP.NET. I am using my own computer to develop the application. I've installed the oracle database on my computer. In order to deploy this application on the server, does the server have to install oracle client? I already included Oracle.DataAccess.dll in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, assuming you're connecting to the database on the same server!

For example, you can connect to remote databases, but the point is where ever the database lives (server or PC), it will need Oracle installed.

Comment: the database is on another server. I will deploy the web app on the web server, which should have oracle client installed?

Comment: Do I need to install visual studio on the web server machine?

Answer (score 0):

The web server you will deploy your application to does not need to have Oracle server but it must have the Oracle client installed (Instant client for instance) + you will have to deploy your database to the Oracle server

Comment: I need to deploy the database too? Sorry I am new in web app

Comment: @AlexSmith, yes, the db instance you have at the moment runs on your machine, you need to install an Oracle server on a server and execute the db scripts to configure your schema

Comment: I installed oracle client on the web server. I also deployed the web application to the web server. How do we configure this oracle client to my application? I configured the oracle client on my local machine and the oracledataaccess.dll is from my machine too.

Comment: @AlexSmith where did you deploy your db?

Comment: the web server oracle client and my computer oracle client will connect to the same database server. How do we deploy the db/

Comment: You'll need to run the sql scripts to build your schema on the oracle server

Comment: where do we run the sql scripts? on web server machine?

Comment: No, on the server on which the Oracle server runs